# Twitter Bootstrap - Labels on top of form fields not aligned

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a form with form elements side by side, and their labels (aligned with the beginning of the respective input element) on top of them, like so:

```
Label                 Label2
+----------------+    +-------+
+----------------+    +-------+
```

The following doesn't work as expected, because "Label2" is slightly unaligned with the input element:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <label class="span9"><span>Label</span></label>
    <label class="span2"><span>Label2</span></label>
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <input type="text" class="span9" />
    <input type="text" class="span2" />
</div>
```

I got it to work using this workaround-ish structure:

```
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="span9">
        <label><span>Label</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <label><span>Label2</span></label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controls controls-row">
    <div class="span9">
        <input type="text" class="span12" />
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <input type="text" class="span12" />
    </div>
</div>
```

So could this be a bug? Because on the [Twitter Bootstrap page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) it says:

> Use .span1 to .span12 for inputs that match the same sizes of the grid columns.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kLuB3/) that reproduces my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the easiest fix is to remove the whitespace in the HTML between the two `input`s:

```
<input type="text" class="span9" />
<input type="text" class="span2" />
```

to:

```
<input type="text" class="span9" /><input type="text" class="span2" />
```

Comment: Additional solutions can be found here:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do it using grid system:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span9">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input name="firstName" class="span12" placeholder="First name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input name="lastName" class="span12" placeholder="Last name" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's misaligned is a whitespace after first `<input>`. This whitespace seems to be an old browsers "feature": they add Unicode SPACE (U+0020) character after an `<input>` immediately followed by other `<input>`, unless they are on the same line in the markup.

You can reduce ancestor's font size to 0, so this space won't be visible:

```
.controls.controls-row { font-size: 0; }​
```

Comment: How could I fall for that x_x Thanks!

Comment: The reason I didn't suggest this is that it doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: This solution prevents you from using relative font sizes (em/percent) in child elements.